# bash: set command: enable the options by overwriting the previous ones

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash

Pretending that the output of `$-` is this:

```
hims
```

If I add options with the `set` command:

```
set -B
```

the output of `$-` becomes this:

```
himBs
```

but I would like it to become this:

```
iBs
```

So that it overwrites the previous options.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the following function to do what you want:

```bsh
myset () {
    options=$-
    options=${options//[is]}  # remove "i" and "s"
    set +"$options"
    set -"$1"
}
```

And call

```
myset B
```

Comment: Yes, ok, after I thought about it but the fact remains that in addition to the options `i` and `s` there are others not to be removed (because it would give an error), for example one of them is option `c`.

Comment: The ideal choice would be to tell the `set` command to ignore the nonexistent options, while working on the others anyway. Is there a switch to do this?

Comment: No, there's no such option.